# Back to top button not triggering properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I have a back to top button that appears when you scroll a little bit .It's working fine but when scrolling if I get to the footer i want the button to go above the footer.

I used the `jquery animate` method to change the `bottom` css rule of the button when I get to the bottom of the page.But that effect doesn't happen instantly on my website because i have more javascript and i think it needs to go through all the code before it runs the effect and It's just not working properly.

Where is the problem ? .Here is what I have done : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dugdzyqw/1/)

```
var offset = 250;
var duration = 500;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});

$('.back-to-top').on('click', function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, duration);
    return false;
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $('.back-to-top').animate({ 'bottom': '400px' });
    } else $('.back-to-top').animate({ 'bottom': '10%' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like adding a class that changes the position of the div, and toggling it when the condition is true solved the problem .